# OpenFin : yo openfin error es5-ext

Tags: html, desktop, node-webkit, yo, openfin

i have probelem with openfin ... you know : [openfin](http://openfin.co/developers.html?url=developers/getting-started/first-app.html)

When i try "**Initiate the generator**"

**"Step 2 - Create a folder, open your command line and enter 
yo openfin
Enter a Name and Description when prompted."**

[image]

**Note**: I have windows 8.1 X64 and I have unistall nodejs and other.

And clean every thing with clean master and restart PC

And try npm cache clean and install nodejs again

And i installed the [es5-ext](https://github.com/medikoo/es5-ext)

Sorry for my bad English, Do you have any idea for this error?

Comment: I would not work on the system32 folder. also did you get this to work?

Comment: hi ,im now in other work .i will try this after 2mothns ;; i do not have the time !

Answer (score 0):

Check whether es5-ext package exist within some of the node_modules folders going up and starting from cli-color\node_modules in path that's mentioned in error stack trace.

If it exists check what's the version in package.json, on that basis we can say something more